# Finding a Regex pattern in R that will allow selection of columns matching the pattern

Tags: r, regex

My skills with regex are a little weak, can anyone help me find a regex to match the following patterns and find them in columns in a dataframe?

Here are the strings.

```
tumor_stroma_epi_ovr_v4..Epithelium.area.µm.2
tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Epithelium.area...m.2
tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2
tumor_stroma_epi_tnbc_v3..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2
tumor_stroma_epi_panc_v5..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2
```

Here are the strings I want to exclude

```
tumor_stroma_epi_ovr_v4..Stroma.area.µm.2
tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Stroma.area...m.2
tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Stroma.area.Âµm.2
tumor_stroma_epi_tnbc_v3..Stroma.area.Âµm.2
tumor_stroma_epi_panc_v5..Stroma.area.Âµm.2
```

Here's the pattern so far, as well as what I've used to test matches

```
pattern <- "^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z]+_v[0-9]+\\.{2}Epithelium\\.area\\.?µm\\.2$"

strings <- c(
  "tumor_stroma_epi_ovr_v4..Epithelium.area.µm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Epithelium.area...m.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_tnbc_v3..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_panc_v5..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_ovr_v4..Stroma.area.µm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Stroma.area...m.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Stroma.area.Âµm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_tnbc_v3..Stroma.area.Âµm.2",
  "tumor_stroma_epi_panc_v5..Stroma.area.Âµm.2"
)

matches <- grepl(pattern, strings)
print(matches)
```

Comment: Based on your example it looks like you could just match by Epithelium, i.e. `grep("Epithelium", strings, value = TRUE)`

Comment: I see what you're going for with your full pattern, but I'd caution that there's a balance in regex in not making a pattern more specific than it needs to be. For example here, your changing suffixes don't seem to be important, assuming that's the case, it's better to exclude them entirely and use a pattern more like `tumor.*?Epithelium\\.area`

Comment: A working version of your full pattern would be `"^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z]+_v[0-9]+\\.{2}Epithelium\\.area\\.+[Âµm]+\\.2$"`

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I'm now trying to integrate that into a later part of my script, but it doesn't seem to be working, namely that I'm getting non-numeric argument to binary operator error. 
The old code looks like this
 t_data <- transform(t_data, tissue_area=tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Epithelium.area...m.2 +
                       tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Necrosis.area...m.2 +
                       tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Stroma.area...m.2 +
                       tumor_stroma_epi_colo_v3..Tumor.area...m.2)
When I change those out to the grep format I get an error.

Comment: To be clear, you want to match the Epithelium strings? And just not match the Stroma strings?

Comment: I'm hoping to have something unique for each tissue type, so one that'll work for Epithelium, one for Stroma, one for Necrosis, and one for Tumor.

Comment: You realize you don't need your regex pattern to match with the whole string, right? `pattern = "Epithelium"` will match any string that contains Eptithelium inside it. Similarly, `pattern = "Stroma"` will match any string that contains Stroma inside it. And `grepl` just returns TRUE and FALSE (the `l` stands for *logical*), so if you want strings that match your usage should be more like `grep(pattern = my_pattern, x =  my_input, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Based on your use of `transform` in your comment, I'm going to suggest you either ask a new question or update this one with a sample of what your data frame looks like. My guess is that the problem you're trying to solve would be better addressed by pivoting your columns into rows, and then using Regex to extract attributes into their own column(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the hard way and describe each part of the strings you deal with, you can fix your current pattern like this:

```r
pattern <- "^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z]+_v[0-9]+\\.{2}Epithelium\\.area\\.*Â?µ?m\\.2$"
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/KW9yKD). Note I replaced `\.?` with `\.*` to cater for multiple dots before UoM, and added `Â?` right after to make sure it also matches an optional `Â`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `tumor_stroma_epi_` - a literal substring
- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `_v` - `_v` text
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `\.{2}` - two dots
- `Epithelium\.area`
- `\.*` - zero or more dots
- `Â?` - an optional `Â`
- `µ?` - an optional `µ`
- `m\.2` - a `m.2` string
- `$` - end of string.